# Cydia deb package doesn't create a shortcut on the main screen

Tags: iphone, ios, cydia

I have a very simple project, I created using `iosopendev.com` and `xcode`.
The program installs correctly in the `/Applications` folder, but does not create a shortcut on the main screen.

Yes, we are talking about jail broken iOS 5 iPhone.

I have created a `Info.plist` and icons and packaged them, but no shortcut appears on the main screen of the iPhone even though the application is being installed in the `/Apllications` folder.

Please, advice.

Answer (score 3):

Grab `UIKitTools` from Cydia. Run `uicache` on the device.

If that doesn't work, respring.

If that doesn't work, reboot.

If that doesn't work either, you screwed up - probably the Info.plist file is corrupted, or the executable filename does not match the one specified in the Info.plist, etc.

Comment: I think, it could be something with the project structure. I made this screenshot of the project structure and the info.plist http://i.imgur.com/WIN3C.png

Answer (score 0):

The [Info.plist file you showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyV0l.png) doesn't have a `CFBundleName`, or a `CFBundleDisplayName` in it.  I'm guessing that SpringBoard needs to see those (particularly `CFBundleDisplayName`) to show your app on the "main" screen.

Also, your `LSRequiresIPhoneOS` value is a `String` equal to `1`.  I would have expected a `Boolean` equal to `YES`.  Not sure if any of these discrepancies are fatal, but since you're not seeing the icon, I would try fixing them, and see if that solves your problem.

You can try looking [at this Apple reference document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW5) regarding what keys and values your Info.plist file should have.